# Context Properties Not Recorded From WPF To Application Insights

Tags: c#, wpf, analytics, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am trying to record telemetry to Application Insights from a WPF app. Events and page views are being logged but the context properties are not being logged alongside them.

I have intitialised the client like:

```
    internal InsightsLogging(string instrumentationKey)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
        configuration.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;

        QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor processor = null;
        configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
            .Use((next) =>
            {
                processor = new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next);
                return processor;
            })
            .Build();

        var QuickPulse = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();
        QuickPulse.Initialize(configuration);
        QuickPulse.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(processor);

        Client = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
        Client.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
        Client.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Client.Context.Device.OperatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
        Client.Context.Device.Id = EnvironmentUtility.GetMACAddress();
        Client.Context.Component.Version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        Client.Context.User.Id = LoggingDataProvider.User;
        Client.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = LoggingDataProvider.User;
        Client.Context.User.AccountId = LoggingDataProvider.Account;
        Client.Context.Component.Version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        Client.Context.User.UserAgent = "App";
    }
```

The logs end up looking like:
[image: Logs]

Notice that none of the "user_*" columns are not populated. And it is worth noting that the appName is incorrect as well - it is the name of the application insights instance on Azure.

Comment: What happens if you fill out the Context of a specific telemetry item like `PageViewTelemetry.Context` as opposed to using the Context property of the TelemetryClient? That is how we do it from our WinForms app and it works.

Comment: Yeah, that worked @PeterBons. Thanks for taking the time. Appreciate it!